# Simple Array syntax error

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to make a program that rolls 5 dice, so I initialized my array `die[5]` and my pointer `*diep` but for some reason it tells me that in those respective lines I am missing a semi colon. From what I can see there is a semi colon in all of the appropriate places. Is there something I am missing?  I have never have used arrays before.

```
int roll_dice (void)
{
    printf ("rolling dice\n");

    int die[5] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}; //initializing my array of dice
    int *diep;  //initializing my pointer

    diep = die;

    diep[5] = rand() % 6 + 1;

    printf ("%s%d", "die = ", *diep);
}
```

Comment: Your compiler might not like having initializers below code (printf).  Try moving your `printf("rolling dice\n");` to below all your initializers.  Also on a side note, `diep[5]` is wrong because your array doesn't have 6 elements.

Comment: Just as a heads up, I don't think you want to access  `diep[5]`, as the last valid value in that array is `diep[4]`

Comment: Also, could you post compiler output? It would be helpful in debugging.

Comment: @JS1 WOAH! it worked thanks so much! It would have taken me hours to figure that out.

Comment: @bearsmahoney JS1 fixed the main problem, but I think you're right with the `diep[4]` fix. Should I replace that everywhere or only in a certain spot?

Comment: @DillonJ. Then you must be using c89. That's old.

Comment: @juanchopanza Obviously he has a non-standard extension or something, as well, since his `//` comments compile.

Comment: @DillonJ. Using `diep[5]` anywhere will produce undesirable results. If you're just trying to access the last element of the array, `diep[4]` will do that for you.

Comment: @IskarJarak Good point, those comments (the subject of my deleted answer) wouldn't work in C89 either.

Comment: @juanchopanza I am using Visual studio 2012 Update 4 if that's helpful

Comment: @DillonJ. I suggest you set up [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html) or [gcc via mingw](http://www.mingw.org/) then, because CL (the Microsoft C/C++ compiler&linker) has pretty terrible support for standard C.

Comment: this line: 'diep[5] = rand() % 6 + 1;'is accessing the 6th element of the array (array indexes start with 0) and this only initializes one entry.  don't you want to initialize all 5 entries in the array?  and when using rand() should always initialize the random function with a call to srand(), something like so: 'srand( time( NULL ) );' Accessing array elements beyond the end of the array results in undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event

Answer (score 1):

Your compiler might not like having initializers below code (the `printf` line). Try moving this line:

```
printf("rolling dice\n");
```

to below all your initializers.

Also on a side note, `diep[5]` is wrong because your array doesn't have 6 elements.  I'm not sure if you intended to roll the dice 5 times or not.  Currently, you are rolling the dice once, putting the result in an out of bounds array element, and then printing the first array element, which will always be 0.